# HowTo make a marching ants border in Morphic?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo, morphic, marching-ants

I am looking for a marching ants border or line in Morphic:

[image: Marching Ants sample]

[Wikipedia describes a possbile algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_ants):

> The easiest way to achieve this animation is by drawing the selection using a pen pattern that contains diagonal lines. If the selection outline is only one pixel thick, the slices out of the pattern will then look like a dashed line, and the animation can easily be achieved by simply shifting the pattern one pixel sideways and redrawing the outline.

As there is probably none readymade, has anybody a hint for me how to create such a border or line?

(The marching ants pattern as a GIF animation is [licensed under CC by Uli Kusterer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Marching_ants_sample_anim.gif))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, Morphic does have it:

```
(PolygonMorph
    vertices: Rectangle fromUser corners
    color: Color transparent
    borderWidth: 2
    borderColor: Color black)
            dashedBorder: {10. 10. Color white. 0. 1};
            openInHand
```

Since this is polygon-based it can not only be a rectangle but any shape.

Comment: Cool, thank you. And "Rectangle fromUser" is a very nice thing, too - i didn't know about that :)